# Apache Spark: how to call UDF over dataset in Java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

What is exact translation of below Scala code snippet in Java?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf 

def upper(s:String) : String = {
    s.toUpperCase
}
val toUpper = udf(upper _)
peopleDS.select(peopleDS(“name”), toUpper(peopledS(“name”))).show
```

Please fill below missing statement in Java:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;

UDF1 toUpper = new UDF1<String, String>() {
    public String call(final String str) throws Exception {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
};

peopleDS.select(peopleDS.col("name"), /* how to run  toUpper("name")) ? */.show();
```

---

#### NOTE

Register UDF, then call using `selectExpr` works for me, but I need something similar to the showen above.

Working example:

```
sqlContext.udf().register(
    "toUpper",
    (String s) -> s.toUpperCase(),
    DataTypes.StringType
);
peopleDF.selectExpr("toUpper(name)","name").show();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java calling UDF without registration is not possible. Please check the following discussion:

- [Using UDFs in Java without registration](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907055755/http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Using-UDFs-in-Java-without-registration-td12497.html)

---

Below is your UDF:

```
private static UDF1 toUpper = new UDF1<String, String>() {
    public String call(final String str) throws Exception {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
};
```

Register the UDF and you can use `callUDF` function.

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

sqlContext.udf().register("toUpper", toUpper, DataTypes.StringType);
peopleDF.select(col("name"),callUDF("toUpper", col("name"))).show();
```

Comment: Your solution helped me solve the problem I was experiencing with udf :  
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)

 This occurred inside my udf where I used a Cipher class from Java library on which I did not have control and could not add 'implements Serializable'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Input csv:

+-------+--------+------+
|   name| address|salary|
+-------+--------+------+
|   Arun|  Indore|     1|
|Shubham|  Indore|     2|
| Mukesh|Hariyana|     3|
|   Arun|  Bhopal|     4|
|Shubham|Jabalpur|     5|
| Mukesh|  Rohtak|     6|
+-------+--------+------+

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local");
        SparkSession sparkSession = new SparkSession(new SparkContext(sparkConf));

        Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.read().option("header", "true")
                .csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Spark\\user.csv");

        /**Create udf*/
        UDF1<String, String> toLower = new UDF1<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String str) throws Exception {
                return str.toLowerCase();
            }
        };

        /**Register udf*/
        sparkSession.udf().register("toLower", toLower, DataTypes.StringType);

        /**call udf using functions.callUDF method*/
        dataset.select(dataset.col("name"),dataset.col("salary"), 
        functions.callUDF("toLower",dataset.col("address")).alias("address")).show();

}

Output :
+-------+------+--------+
|   name|salary| address|
+-------+------+--------+
|   Arun|     1|  indore|
|Shubham|     2|  indore|
| Mukesh|     3|hariyana|
|   Arun|     4|  bhopal|
|Shubham|     5|jabalpur|
| Mukesh|     6|  rohtak|
+-------+------+--------+
```