# How to apply user-defined function to column (gives "Task not serializable" when adding a column)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to append this column generated by the method 'strToInt' which is turning out to be not serializable.

```
def strToInt(colVal : String) : Int = {
  var str = new Array[String](3)
  str(0) = "icmp"; str(1) = "tcp"; str(2) = "udp"
  var i = 0
  for (i <- 0 to str.length-1) {
    if (str(i) == colVal) { return i }
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("This never happens")
}
val strtoint = udf(strToInt(_:String)).apply(col("Atr 1"))
val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", strtoint)
```

I have tried putting the function in a helper class this way,

```
object Helper extends Serializable {
    def strToInt ...     
                                    }
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to be as follows where the function execution is at `withColumn` level (not when the UDF is defined).

```
// define a UDF
val strtoint = udf(strToInt _)
// use it (aka execute)
val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", strtoint(col("Atr 1")))
```

That *seemingly* little change changes what you create and how you execute it afterwards.

As you may have noticed already, [udf](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@udf[RT,A1](f:A1=%3ERT)(implicitevidence$2:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[RT],implicitevidence$3:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A1]):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction) creates a user-defined function that Spark SQL understands (can can execute):

> **udf[RT, A1](f: (A1) ⇒ RT): UserDefinedFunction** Defines a user-defined function of 1 arguments as user-defined function (UDF).

(I removed the implicit parameters to ease comprehension)

Quoting the scaladoc of [UserDefinedFunction](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction):

> A user-defined function. To create one, use the `udf` functions in functions.

Not much I agree, but the "protocol" is to register a UDF first before you can execute it in your queries, say `withColumn` or `select` operators.

---

I'd also change `strToInt` to be more Scala-idiomatic (and hopefully easier to comprehend, too).

```
def strToInt(colVal : String) : Int = {
  val strs = Array("icmp", "tcp", "udp")
  strs.indexOf(colVal)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! Could you also explain what  the previous syntax did (and expected) compared to the current one?

Comment: Hope the comments gave you some insight. The point is that you wanted to define **and** execute the UDF at once which is not what you wanted.

Comment: It has to do with type. When you do this:
`val strtoint = udf(strToInt _)`
the type of `strtoint` is `UserDefinedFunction` which is serializable case class
When you do this:
`val strtoint = udf(strToInt(_:String)).apply(col("Atr 1"))`
`strtoint` is a type `Function1[String, UserDefinedFunction]`, basically an anonymous function that generates a `UserDefinedFunction`.  `Function1` is not serializable. Spark needs it to be serializable so it can ship it out to each node that is performing distributed operations on your DataFrame.

Comment: @kapunga Thanks for that. I have a quick follow up question. I want to keep the 'object Helper' and put the 'str' variable as an object variable (so it can be assigned from outside). However, this fails to execute with the line of syntax, giving "Failed to execute User defined function". I don't understand.

Comment: Place `strToInt` or the UDF in `Helper` object and it's supposed to just work. What issues do you face?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Okay, that worked. I put the 'udf' in the object. The problem was with displaying the column from the modified dataframe i.e., when I did newDF.select("newCol").show() after recreating the dataframe (successfully; without errors). What I did,   `val strtoint = udf(Helper.strToInt _) ` ;  `val newDF = df.withColumn("newCol", Helper.strtoint(col("Atr 1")))` . Why did this not work?

Comment: What errors do you have? Can you share the `Helper` as an edit to your question?

Comment: I keep on reading that UDFs are bad for performance... or is that not really so?

Comment: @thebluephantom It could be a bottleneck. It however depends on what UDF are we talking about. Simples ones are harmless.

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding what's going on here is that while Scala is a functional programming language, it runs on the JVM which does not have support for a functional type.  At runtime, any `val` assigned an "anonymous" or "lambda" function will actually be an instance of an anonymous class with an `apply` method. So let's say you have the following:

```
object helper {
  val isNegative: (Int => Boolean) = (n: Int) => n < 0
}
```

This compiles to the same thing as this:

```
object helper {
  val isNegative: Function1[Int, Boolean] = {
    def apply(n: Int): Boolean = n < 0
  }
}
```

`isNegative` is really an anonymous class instance extending the trait `Function1`. When you instead do this:

```
object helper {
  def isNegative(n: Int): Boolean = n < 0
}
```

Now `isNegative` is a method of the object `helper` instead. When it comes to dealing with Spark, if you were to do something like this:

```
// ds is a Dataset[Int]
ds.filter(isNegative)
```

In the first case Spark will have to serialize the anonymous class assigned to `isNegative` and fail because it is not serializable. In the second case, it will have to serialize `helper` which does work because an `object` is serializable if all it's state is serializable.

To apply this to your problem, when you do this:

```
val strtoint = udf(strToInt(_:String)).apply(col("Atr 1"))
```

at runtime what `strtoint` is is an anonymous class instance with the trait `Funtion1[String, UserDefinedFunction]`, that is a method that generates a UserDefinedFunction when it is a called. With the underscore filled in, it is identical to this:

```
val strtoInt: Function1[String, UserDefinedFunction] = new Function1[String, UserDefinedFunction] = {
  def apply(t1: String) = udf(strToInt(t1 :String)).apply(col("Atr 1"))
}
```

to minimally change you code, you can just change the `val` to a `def`:

```
def sti = udf(strToInt(_:String)).apply(col("Atr 1"))
```

Now `sti` is a member function of it's enclosing class, and if that is serializable, you should be good as far as Spark is concerned. The other thing to keep in mind here is that `strToInt` also needs to be part of a serializable `class` or `object`

The other way to fix this as has been suggested would be to change `val strtoint` to a `UserDefinedFunction` which is a `case class` and thus serializable, however you still need to make sure that `strToInt` is a member of a serializable `class` or `object`.

Comment: What did you change in `strtoint` vs `sti`?

Comment: It went from a `val` to a `def`. There is a difference in how these are treated by Scala.  In the case of a `val`, you assign an instance of type `Function1` to `strtoint` at runtime.  This instance is what Spark attempts to serialize and fails because `Function1` is not serializable. When you use `def` with `sti`, it is instead a member method of some `class` or `object` and if that `class` or `object` is serializable (for instance if the `class` is a `case class` or the `object` has only serializable members) then Spark has no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be similar to the problem I was experiencing (In Java).
My udf function was using Cipher library to encrypt something and the exception that was thrown is :

`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.crypto.Cipher
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: javax.crypto.Cipher, value: javax.crypto.Cipher@625d02ce)`

I could not add 'implements Serializable' to Cipher class because it was a library provided by Java.

I used the following solution from this link : [spark-how-to-call-udf-over-dataset-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383836/1243031)

```
private static UDF1 toUpper = new UDF1<String, String>() {
    public String call(final String str) throws Exception {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
};
```

Register the UDF and you can use callUDF function.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

sqlContext.udf().register("toUpper", toUpper, DataTypes.StringType);
peopleDF.select(col("name"),callUDF("toUpper", col("name"))).show();
```

Where instead of calling str.toUpperCase(); I called my Cipher instance.